# marriage, sect, politics

Tags: practical-islam, nikah, imaan, sects, politics

asalamalyakum,
I am a practicing muslima, my parents are highly educated people but my dad and siblings arent practicing muslims. I wasnt a practicing muslim either until 9 months ago, a big trauma has opened my eyes to reality. I have a marriage proposal of a well educated and well mannered, practicing muslim man. My parents are against this marriage proposal because this man is pakistani pashtun and not afghan pashtun. I have talked to them in various ways regarding this but they keep up bringing other proposals of men who arent practicing muslims and arent good people if i must say. They said aslong he is from our country doesnt matter. ITs really hard to find a good pious future partner and since i have found one my parents are against it just because of our sect.
Secondly my family talks alot about politics and its getting too much westernised since i have changed and have become more religious, my family and i we end up in many arguments even if i try to ignore its impossiple to keep them happy. They keep thinking im wrong and im getting brainwashed. They say they love me but treat me as a non worthy person.
I have sought help from many places but ended up with no results although i have put my whole trust in allah i have no worries. But my parents are telling me im too young to marry and im still a kid, Im 24 years old and i have been ready to get married long time ago.
Any advice regarding this situation?